# Accessing google sql database with external app in android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

So I realize you cannot directly connect an app to the database directly.  So what I did was create a GAE (google apps engine) backend with the external app which will access the database.

External app->backend->google cloud sql

However I am confused as to where I put the address of the google SQL server in the GAE backend.  Would it go under enable google cloud sql which is under the properties for the app engine?

This is with an already existing google cloud database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the address (and username and password) of the Cloud SQL instance when you create a connection:

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/database",
    "user", "password");

See https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/dev-access